# Working with the Passthrough Composite Layer on VR Headsets

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, experimental-design

Before I begin, I am fully aware of the risks involved with altering the passthrough camera feed for the end user. This is for a specific use-case and will not be a publicly available. I'm attempting to reduce the framerate of the environment for the end user.

Here is a similar example done with custom hardware: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fNp37zFn9Q however, I'd like to use one of the major headset brands that don't require a PC connection (untethered)

I've done some initial research and it seems that most SDKs (Oculus, Vive, Pico) do not grant the developer access to the passthrough camera stream other than the ability to adjust its opacity, brightness, hue, styling, etc.

I'd like to produce this project in Unity but it's not a requirement and assume I can gain developer access to any headset that might support this and willing to void some warrantees.

So far I've only read documentation and searched SDK script files for references to render textures in files that relate to the passthrough systems. It's pretty obvious this is prevented by default but I'm hoping to find a way to override it. I'm also aware I could just attempt to slow the headset down by running a lot of random operations on the main thread but I'd rather not do this as the results may be inconsistent and also drain the battery.

Relevant Documentation  https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-passthrough,
https://hub.vive.com/storage/docs/en-us/UnityXR/UnityXRPassthrough.html,
https://developer-global.pico-interactive.com/document/unity/seethrough